# Access enum values in Rails model with integer value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, enums

In my Rails application, I have a model called `Form`. In `From` model, there is a enum `enum form_type: [:formA, :formB, :formC]`.

I have a json file called `form.json` which has seed data for different types of forms. I basically need to call corresponding seed data for different types of form correctly.

```
{
    "formA" : "seed data1",
    "formB" : "seed data2",
    "formC" : "seed data3",
}
```

Let's say I retrieve this json data in a variable called `json_data`. And I create `Form` model in a following way.

I create the `Form` models like below way.:

```
new_form = Form.create(form_type: params[:form_type], form_data: __ ] )
```

Using `params[:form_type]`, I need to get string value of `form_type` from the enum. However, if I do `Form.form_types`, I get `{"formA" => 0, "formB" => 1, "formC" => 2}` instead of `[:formA, :formB, :formC]`. Thus, it makes me really hard to get the string type of `form_type`. How can I retrieve `form_type` from the enum using the integer value?

Comment: if `Form.form_types` gives you `{"formA" => 0, "formB" => 1, "formC" => 2}` then `Form.form_types.keys` will give you `["formA", "formB", "formC"]`

Comment: That works. Why don't you add a answer so I can select your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `Form.form_types` gives you `{"formA" => 0, "formB" => 1, "formC" => 2}` then `Form.form_types.keys` will give you `["formA", "formB", "formC"]`